# WebService REST con Genexus

Tags: java, genexus, rest

Hice un WebService REST en Genexus Ev2, pero tengo problemas para comsumirlo a través de una aplicación angular. Al tratar de consumirlo, me tira error 403, pero si lo pruebo con Postman o Advanced REST Client (Extensiones de chrome) obtengo la respuesta sin problema.

Usé Genexus generando java.

Esta es la excecpión que me arroja:

```
abr 13, 2016 7:58:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:200)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$600(WebApplicationImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$12.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:698)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$12.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:695)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:197)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:695)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:690)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:438)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:287)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:587)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:213)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:516)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

abr 13, 2016 7:58:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet JerseyListener
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:87)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:117)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:200)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1182)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$600(WebApplicationImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$12.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:698)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$12.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:695)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:197)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:695)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:690)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:438)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:287)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:587)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:213)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:516)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Saben qué puede ser ?

Comment: Por favor, agregue mas información en la pregunta sobre qué ha intentando y/o muéstrenos cuál fragmento del código no está funcionando.

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor muestra si hay algún mensaje de error y/o stacktrace involucrado. Quizás pueda ser que falte que envíes alguna cabecera desde tu aplicación angular, que te falte enviar algún dato, que la información no sea correcta, etc.

Comment: HTTP 403 Corresponde a Forbidden, supongo que por Postman no envías ningun tipo de autenticación así que es posible que soo sea una url incorrecta

Comment: Si con Postman o Rest Client obtienes la respuesta ***puedes dar por correcta toda la parte java***, por favor adjunta el código Angular correspondiente a la vista, el controlador asociado y el servicio que hace la petición REST.

Comment: Ahora me tira Error 500, y una excepción, que la dejé en el cuerpo del mensaje.
La URL es la correcta.

Comment: Aclaro que en el web.xml del Tomcat tengo habilitado el CORS. Ya he utilizado este tipo de webservices en otras intancias, pero en este proyecto no se por qué me tira ésto.

Comment: Si te da un 500 el problema esta en el server,vuelve a ver si por PostMan funciona, porque no tiene sentido que por PostMan si funcione y por llamada Angular no

Comment: Por lo que estoy viendo puede ser que tengas diferentes implementaciones de JAXB y esto puede dar conflicto de librerías, pero de ser así, el servidor no respondería nunca bien a la petición REST sea realizada de la forma que sea(navegador,postman, aplicación angular,etc)

Comment: Me salta la misma excepción tanto por Postman como por Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me voy a arriesgar con la respuesta, creo que tienes un conflicto de librerías JAXB en el classpath que carga tu proyecto

Mira este [issue reportado](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5894) y comprueba que es la misma excepción.

Comment: Si, efectivamente. Me bajé las últimas versiones, las reemplacé y todo anduvo de maravilla.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si no es mucho pedir, por favor aprueba la respuesta o marcala como útil, muchas gracias